# Field code to display equation numbers in Word

Tags: ms-word, label, equation

I am trying to write an article with some equations in Word; however, I encountered trouble related to displaying equation number with field code.

For example, I put a+b with the tool of Insert an Equation and insert the reference number just after the pound key with Caption tool.

To refer to this equation, I put the field code by using the Insert Cross-referencing tool.
However, even though I choose only label and number, Word shows the equation's entire, including both equation number and equation itself.

[captured image](https://imgur.com/GWcUGMa.gif) (I just put the imgur link because I could not upload the captured image due to less reputation)

What I need is to display only the equation number.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately, you may not receive an answer here and your question may be closed without one because it is off-topic.  This is a forum about programming, not about using applications like Word.https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It would be fine in the SuperUser forum. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word

Comment: Perhaps: http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CombineXrefs.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon
Thank you for your answering to my question. I did not know this post is not related to on-topic.

Comment: @macropod This site seems to be useful. Thank you very much!